# Sacar un float y un int de un Char array

Tags: c

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Local{
    char nombre[49];
    char tipo[49];
    int valor;
    float latitud;
    float longitud;
    int apertura;
    int cierre;
};

int main(){
    struct Local str;
    int seleccion = 0, contador = 0, i = 0, j = 0;
    char local[122];
    printf("Welcome to LS Maps\n\n");
    while (seleccion <= 0 || seleccion > 4){
    printf("1. Add location | 2. List locations | 3. Show suggestions | 4. Exit\n");
    printf("Selected action ");
    scanf("%d", &seleccion);
    if (seleccion <= 0 || seleccion > 4){
        printf("\n\nERROR: Wrong action number\n\n");
    }
    if (seleccion == 1){
        if (contador == 10){
            printf ("\nThe system has reached the maximum number of locations\n\n");
            seleccion = 0;
        }
        else{
            printf("\nLocation information: ");
            scanf("%s", local);
            while(local[i] != '#'){
                str.nombre[i] = local[i];
                i++;
            }
            if (local[i] == '#'){
                i++;
            }
            while(local[i] != '#'){
                str.tipo[j] = local[i];
                j++;
                i++;
            }
            if (local[i] == '#'){
                i++;
            }
            while(local[i] != '#'){
                str.valor = local[i];
                i++;
            }
            printf("%s\n", str.nombre);
            printf("%s\n", str.tipo);
            printf("%c\n", str.valor);
        }
    }
    
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Tengo que sacar un int de un array pedido.

EJ: nombre#tipoDeLocalización#valoración#latitud|longitud#horaDeApertura-horaDeCierre

No es posible usar Atof ni Atoi, necesito sacar los valores de valoricacion y longitud y latitud para usarlos despues en unas ecuaciones.

Ya que nos pide más tarde que localizaciones están más cerca y cosas así, pero solo tengo la cuestion de hacer parte del array en int o floats.

Comment: Bueno, si tu profesor no te deja usar `atoi` ni `atof`, sorpréndelo usando `sscanf`. Ya usas `scanf` en tu codigo, usar `sscanf` se te dara natural

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza [`strtok_r`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Finding-Tokens-in-a-String.html#Finding-Tokens-in-a-String) para encontrar los caracteres delimitados en el string, o sea, para encontrar los datos que quieres obtener separados por `#`, `|` o `-`.

En el caso que lo que estés buscando sea un string, simplemente copia los valores en el struct, y en el caso de que sean valores numéricos, parséalos y guárdalos en el struct.

Te dejo un código que hace precisamente eso

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

struct Local
{
    char nombre[49];
    char tipo[49];
    int valor;
    float latitud;
    float longitud;
    int apertura;
    int cierre;
};

int main()
{
    char str[] = "nombre#tipoDeLocalización#1#2.3|4.5#0900-21000";

    struct Local local;

    const char* delim = "#";
    char* rest;

    char* name_start = strtok_r(str, delim, &rest);
    if (name_start == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "No se pudo leer el nombre del local\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    strncpy(local.nombre, name_start, 49);
    local.nombre[48] = '\0'; // ensure the string is null terminated

    // check if is null
    char* tipo_start = strtok_r(rest, delim, &rest);
    strncpy(local.tipo, tipo_start, 49);
    local.tipo[48] = '\0'; // ensure the string is null terminated

    char* valor = strtok_r(rest, delim, &rest);
    if (valor == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "No se pudo leer el ¿valor?\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    char* endptr = valor;
    errno = 0;
    long long_val = strtol(valor, &endptr, 10); // parsear el string
    if (valor == endptr) {
        fprintf(stderr, "No tiene un ¿valor? válido\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    } else if (errno != 0) {
        perror("Error al leer el ¿valor?");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    local.valor = long_val;

    // check if is null
    char* longitude = strtok_r(rest, "|", &rest);
    local.longitud = strtof(longitude, NULL); // check errors here

    // check if is null
    char* latitude = strtok_r(rest, delim, &rest);
    local.latitud = strtof(latitude, NULL); // check errors here

    // check if is null
    char* time_start = strtok_r(rest, "-", &rest);
    local.apertura = strtol(time_start, NULL, 10); // check errors here

    // check if is null
    local.cierre = strtol(rest, NULL, 10); // check errors here

    printf(
        "nombre: %s, tipo: %s, valor: %i, longitud: %f, latitud: %f, apertura: %i, cierre: %i",
        local.nombre,
        local.tipo,
        local.valor,
        local.longitud,
        local.latitud,
        local.apertura,
        local.cierre
    );

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Obviamente le falta checar que existan errores y eso es un *must-do* para cualquier aplicación, pero eso es aparte, de todas formas te dejé dos ejemplos para verficar los errores.

Quizá hubiera sido más sencillo utilizar `scanf`, sin embargo no es muy recomendable pues precisamente no es tan sencillo recuperarte de errores, en caso de que existan. `scanf` está diseñado para situaciones en las que lo que vas a leer está perfectamente formateado con el formato adecuado. Pero dado que tu aplicación lee los datos del usuario, no puedes estar seguro de que así va a ser. [Esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58403537/what-can-i-use-for-input-conversion-instead-of-scanf) pregunta tiene más detalles de `scanf` y sus peligros.